# How to consecutively add pictures to a table in ReactJS on button click

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add pictures to a table where the user clicks a button and an image goes to the first cell, they press it again and the second image goes in the 2nd cell, and so on and so on. I was trying to do something like this:

```
<tr className = "tableRow">
                <td><img src = {this.state.Array[0].image}  alt = "" /></td>
                <td><img src = {this.state.Array[1].image} alt = ""/></td>
                <td><img src = {this.state.Array[2].image} alt = ""/></td>
              </tr>
```

and then on the click of the button just push a new image to the state array. Of course I failed to realize that until the image was pushed to the array, Array[x] would be undefined and rendering would fail.

I figured I could just put empty strings in the array and then replace them with images, but I got this feeling that there was a much better way to go about doing this that I am missing.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What does your table look like?  Do you have a fixed number of colums and rows, or what are they base on?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat it's a 3x3 table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional to only display the `img` element if the array length is large enough

```
<td>
  { this.state.Array.length > 0 ? <img src={this.state.Array[0]} alt="" />
    : null }
</td>
```

Comment: Better written as `{this.state.Array.length > 0 && <img src={this.state.Array[0]} alt="" />}`

Comment: @Matthew this worked great, but could you clarify a little what's happening here?

Comment: @WebbH [Check this out](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate over all of the images that are currently stored in the state, so that only the images that are in the array will be rendered, and as they are added or removed, the number of images will be updated.

Don't forget about including a unique key for each element though. You may have a better way of doing this, but for now I created keys based on the array index (not ideal).

```
return (
    <tr className="tableRow">
        {this.state.Array.map((image, index) => (
            <td key={`td-${index}`}>
                <img key={`img=${index}`} src={image.image} alt="" />
            </td>
        ))}
    </tr>
)
```

Comment: Just to add to this. If you're concerned that your `this.state.Array` might be empty when the component initially mounts, then you can use `{this.state.Array && this.Array.map((image, index) => .......`